# Python Flask WTForms datetime validate another

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Is it possible to do validation on a datetime field in WTForms comparing it to another datetime?

I have the form

```
class EventEdit(FlaskForm):
timeIn = DateTimeField('Time In', validators=[DataRequired()])
timeOut = DateTimeField('Time Out', validators=[DataRequired()])
reason = RadioField('Reason', choices=[
    ('Incident','Incident'),
    ('Gym','Gym'),
    ('Meeting','Meeting'),
    ('Other','Other')])
comment = StringField('Additional Comments')
submit = SubmitField('Save Changes')
```

I need to make sure when timeOut is entered it is greater than timeIn.

Additionally, I haven't been able to get the timeOut field to be optional yet either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `validate` function in your class. But make sure to first call the `Form.validate(self)`, because it's still needed to validate the individual fields.

```
class EventEdit(FlaskForm):
    timeIn = DateTimeField('Time In', validators=[DataRequired()])
    timeOut = DateTimeField('Time Out', validators=[DataRequired()])
    reason = RadioField('Reason', choices=[
        ('Incident','Incident'),
        ('Gym','Gym'),
        ('Meeting','Meeting'),
        ('Other','Other')])
    comment = StringField('Additional Comments')
    submit = SubmitField('Save Changes')
    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        if self.timeIn.data < self.timeOut.data:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this so i could validate on multiple fields

```
def validate_timeOut(self, timeOut):
    if self.timeIn.data > self.timeOut.data:
        self.timeOut.errors.append('Time must be after Time In')
        return False
    else:
        return True

def validate_comment(self, comment):
    if len(self.comment.data) > 120:
        self.comment.errors.append('Comment is too long!')
        return False
    else:
        return True
```